# htaccess strip everything after .html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have a couple external websites that are linking to our site, but their code is malformed and causing problems with the link which makes Google think we have more 404's on our site than we actually do.

What's happening is their malformed code is adding ASCII characters after the .html which represent their closing anchor tag.

So, what I'm trying to do in my htaccess file is strip everything after the .html and redirect to the clean .html URL (without causing an endless loop).

Here's a couple samples of what is coming in...

```
> http://www.site.com/pagename.html&quot;&gt;
> http://www.site.com/pagename.html&lt;/a&gt;
```

And I would like to redirect those to...

```
http://www.site.com/pagename.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to match those which has `.+` (one or more chars) *after* the `.html` and perform a redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Capture everything before .html into $1 (non-greedy)
# And do a redirection appending only .html onto $1
RewriteRule (.+?)\.html.+$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.html [L,R=301]
```

And since you are doing redirections rather than rewrites, you could also do this via `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch permanent (.+?)\.html.+$ http://example.com/$1.html
```

Comment: Thanks Michael - I am very close now with your help. The redirect URL is clean now at the end, but it's redirecting from www.site.com/pagename.html&lt;/a&gt; to www.site.com/var/www/site.com/pagename.html.  I tried a couple different things to try to fix that but I think I'm doing more harm than good.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Rmilligan2372 See above - I added the protocol and host to the redirect.  I always forget that if this is done in htaccess instead of at the server config, the rewrite isn't preceded by `/` which messes up redirects when apache looks in the file system.